# Python number with comma as 1000 separator

Tags: python, numbers, format

Easy task:

```
number = 100123.44
number_formated = "100,123"
```

Don't tell me there is no better way than:

```
number_formated = "{:,}".format(int(format("{:.0f}".format(number))))
```

?

Comment: "{:,}".format(int(number))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the number with `,` as a thousands separator as a whole number, use this format string:

```
number_formated = "{:,.0f}".format(number)
```

No need to nest two calls and cast the resulting string to int again.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply call `int` on your `number` without formatting:

```
number_formatted = "{:,}".format(int(number))
```

If you use Python 3.6 or higher you can use [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
number_formatted = f'{int(number):,}'
```

Edit: using [Christian König](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6725184/christian-k%c3%b6nig) answer we can remove the `int` call:

```
number_formatted = f"{number:,.0f}"
```

Comment: Note that `int(number)` truncates the decimal digits, while `f"{number:,.0f}"` rounds. `int(1.9)` gives `1`, but `f"{1.9:,.0f}"` gives `2`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this
    `formatted_number = "{:,}".format(number)`

Comment: While this correctly prints `,` as a thounsands separator, the fractional digits are not removed.